# when textfield empty pop up a message box like facebook after pressing button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, facebook

i am doing a social network website in asp.net c#, so i want to [pop up this](https://scontent-a-cdg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10885297_1502929813329928_5824253485648326540_n.jpg?oh=9d9b3f29cef22020c5dc59a60da00e6c&oe=5544302E) alert box after pressing the post button when it's empty.

i have used this code as requiredfieldvalidater , but it's pop up for every button i pressed

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" required="required" placeholder=" What is in your mind"   style="margin-left: 17px; margin-top: 14px" BorderStyle="Groove" TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Size="Large" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" ValidationGroup="a"   ></asp:TextBox>
```

so i want another code [Like this](https://scontent-a-cdg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10885297_1502929813329928_5824253485648326540_n.jpg?oh=9d9b3f29cef22020c5dc59a60da00e6c&oe=5544302E)
could somebody tell me how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an audio file element

```
<audio src="pop.mp3" id="pop_sound"></audio>
```

then in javascript just add the onclick handler

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('TextBox1').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
     if(e.keyCode===YOURKEY){
         document.getElementById('pop_sound').play();
         alert('YOUR MESSAGE!');
     }
 }); 
</script>
```